# inArray, indexOf in a 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

i have an 2-dimensional array. for example

```
var bruecken = [[1,2],[3,4]];
```

now i am trying to test, if a subarray exists:

```
console.log(jQuery.inArray([1,2], bruecken));
```

or

```
console.log(bruecken.indexOf([1,2]));
```

but both ways it returns -1. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search multi-dimensional array JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809425/search-multi-dimensional-array-javascript)

Comment: you know, you can upvote answers which you find helpful... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would be to use a for loop and compare them, then return if found. Here is something you can work with, I used JSON for comparison, but you can just use whatever comparator you find best (there are plenty):

```
function arrayInArray(needle, haystack) {
    var i=0, len=haystack.length, target=JSON.stringify(needle);
    for(; i<len; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(haystack[i]) == target) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

arrayInArray( [0,1], [ [1,2], [0,1] ] ); // 1
```

If you want booleans, just return `true` instead of `i` and `false` instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think inArray will work because comparing two identical arrays using `==` will return false. You could try using `grep` instead:

```
function subArrayInArray(subArray, array){
    var matches = $.grep(array, function(a){
        // Compare the target array with each of the child arrays
        return $(subArray).not(a).length == 0 && $(a).not(subArray).length == 0;
    });
    return !!matches.length;    
}
```

The method for comparing two arrays was stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays)

Comment: thanks! thats what i need. could you please provide a sample code for a function like `inArray(matches, target)` that returns boolean?

Comment: changed to function that returns boolean, as requested