# jQuery select object from array that contains all values from another object

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects, something like this example:

```
var b = [
  {
    'super_attribute[170]': "41", 
    'super_attribute[171]': "15",
    'data': 1
  },
  {
    'super_attribute[150]': "401", 
    'super_attribute[181]': "5",
    'test': 1234
  }
];
```

I want to select the object out of the array that has the `attribute` and `value` values from `a`

```
var a = {
  'super_attribute[170]': "41", 
  'super_attribute[171]': "15"
};
```

Is this possible with array filters or mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search multi-dimensional array JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809425/search-multi-dimensional-array-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
var filtered = b.filter(function(item){

return item.attribute == 'something' && item.value == 1;

});
```

edit: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you'll find the documentation to filter

Comment: I just edited my original question with the updated code that I should have posted in the first place. The issue is that I the values in the object `a` will change

Comment: if the values in a change then don't compare like @Manish suggested with static values - rather compare with the right key from a: item.attribute == a.attribute ... ;)