# Find array A in a multidimensional array B using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I need a fast way to find the one array in another.

The following example describes the scenario I have:

I need to find the array A:

```
var A = ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"];
```

In array B (please note, my B array may hold millions of results):

```
B[
["X0", "O0", "I0", "Z2", "T2", "L0", "V2"],
["I0", "V2", "O0", "T0", "L4", "X0", "Z3"],
["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"],
["Z2", "L7", "T0", "I1", "V3", "X0", "O0"],
["Z3", "I1", "O0", "T3", "X0", "L2", "V2"],
["O0", "X0", "I1", "T2", "V0", "Z3", "L2"],
["I0", "Z0", "L7", "X0", "V3", "O0", "T3"],
["L3", "X0", "I1", "O0", "V0", "Z1", "T1"]
];
```

Is there a function that would either provide me with a true or false statement, or with an actual result which in the above case is: **B[2]**

Comment: does the order matters? is ther only one find inside? what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Nina, the order doesn't matter. All I want is to include array A in the array B, without duplicating it. So the idea is first to check that A is not occurring in B.

Comment: are ther duplicate entries in sub arrays, or in the find array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search multi-dimensional array JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809425/search-multi-dimensional-array-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no duplicates in the find array, you could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
function getIndex(needle, haystack) {
    return haystack.findIndex(h => needle.every(n => h.includes(n)));
}

var a = ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"],
    b = [["X0", "O0", "I0", "Z2", "T2", "L0", "V2"], ["I0", "V2", "O0", "T0", "L4", "X0", "Z3"], ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"], ["Z2", "L7", "T0", "I1", "V3", "X0", "O0"], ["Z3", "I1", "O0", "T3", "X0", "L2", "V2"], ["O0", "X0", "I1", "T2", "V0", "Z3", "L2"], ["I0", "Z0", "L7", "X0", "V3", "O0", "T3"], ["L3", "X0", "I1", "O0", "V0", "Z1", "T1"]];
    
console.log(getIndex(a, b));
```

Comment: this seems to work... do you think it will perform well once the B array gets really large (hundreds of thousands or millions) of indexes?

Comment: @jjj, you could try it and if it is to slow, then you could use some nested for loops with early exit.

Comment: For now, I've decided to implement your method Nina, because the other recommended option is using JSON.stringify which I think adds a bit of complexity and may slow down the results. Once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the **order of items in `A` matters**, then use `find` and `JSON.stringify`

```
var aStr = JSON.stringify( A );
var doesExists = !!B.find( s => JSON.stringify( s ) == aStr );
```

**Demo**

```js
var B = [
["X0", "O0", "I0", "Z2", "T2", "L0", "V2"],
["I0", "V2", "O0", "T0", "L4", "X0", "Z3"],
["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"],
["Z2", "L7", "T0", "I1", "V3", "X0", "O0"],
["Z3", "I1", "O0", "T3", "X0", "L2", "V2"],
["O0", "X0", "I1", "T2", "V0", "Z3", "L2"],
["I0", "Z0", "L7", "X0", "V3", "O0", "T3"],
["L3", "X0", "I1", "O0", "V0", "Z1", "T1"]
];
var A = ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"];

var aStr = JSON.stringify( A );
var doesExists = !!B.find( s => JSON.stringify( s ) == aStr );

console.log( doesExists );
```

And **if the order doesn't matter** then use `sort` as first before comparing.

```
var fnSort = (a,b) => a.localeCompare( b );
var aStr = JSON.stringify( A.sort( fnSort ) );
var doesExists = !!B.find( s => JSON.stringify( s.sort( fnSort ) ) == aStr );
```

**Demo**

```js
var B = [
["X0", "O0", "I0", "Z2", "T2", "L0", "V2"],
["I0", "V2", "O0", "T0", "L4", "X0", "Z3"],
["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"],
["Z2", "L7", "T0", "I1", "V3", "X0", "O0"],
["Z3", "I1", "O0", "T3", "X0", "L2", "V2"],
["O0", "X0", "I1", "T2", "V0", "Z3", "L2"],
["I0", "Z0", "L7", "X0", "V3", "O0", "T3"],
["L3", "X0", "I1", "O0", "V0", "Z1", "T1"]
];
var A = ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"];

var fnSort = (a,b) => a.localeCompare( b );
var aStr = JSON.stringify( A.sort( fnSort ) );
var doesExists = !!B.find( s => JSON.stringify( s.sort( fnSort ) ) == aStr );

console.log( doesExists );
```

Comment: This is great, but I wonder about the performance of JSON.stringify on B array at the point when it contains million+  indexes. Can you contemplate about this?

Comment: @jjj For million+ indexes most approaches would struggle unless you **prep** the data and created indexes prior to the search.. Best way to check is to measure the performance based upon your own specific requirements of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use find operator and compare if the array is included in and other array since arrays are objects you can't compare the directly, because they are different instances, to compare them you can try this trick converting them in strings...

```js
var A = ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"];

var B = [
["X0", "O0", "I0", "Z2", "T2", "L0", "V2"],
["I0", "V2", "O0", "T0", "L4", "X0", "Z3"],
["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"],
["Z2", "L7", "T0", "I1", "V3", "X0", "O0"],
["Z3", "I1", "O0", "T3", "X0", "L2", "V2"],
["O0", "X0", "I1", "T2", "V0", "Z3", "L2"],
["I0", "Z0", "L7", "X0", "V3", "O0", "T3"],
["L3", "X0", "I1", "O0", "V0", "Z1", "T1"],
["A0", "B0", "C0", "D2", "E2", "F0", "G2"]
];

function isIncluded(element) {
  return element.toString() == A.toString();
}

console.log(B.find(isIncluded)); // 130
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var result = B.filter(function(bArr){ return bArr.length == A.length && bArr.every(function(ele,index){ return ele==A[index]})})
```